# Login with google in the Salesforce SDK in react native

Tags: authentication, mobilesdk, react-native

We are building an application where we need to use the google login the login to salesforce. We have setup everything in our salesforce environment to enable this.

When we do it with the browser it works like a charm, but we when we try it in our react native app we get the disallowed_useragent error from google.

We understand this is because the Salesforce SDK uses a webview for this.

Is there a way to get this working with the Salesforce SDK in react native? If so how?